# how to retrieve a MySQL function definition with perl DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

```
$dbh->selectrow_hashref("SHOW CREATE FUNCTION my_func");
```

returns

```
0  HASH(0x202fe70)
   'Create Function' => undef
   'Database Collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci'
   'Function' => 'my_func'
   'character_set_client' => 'cp850'
   'collation_connection' => 'cp850_general_ci'
   'sql_mode' => ''
```

(the function definition is missing)

The same code works perfectly with SHOW CREATE VIEW, and SHOW CREATE FUNCTION works on the MySQL command line with the same credentials.

I wondered if the data type is too large for the attribute, so I tried setting LongReadLen to a very large number on the connect, but it made no difference.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $dbh->selectrow_hashref("SHOW CREATE FUNCTION my_func");`

Comment: this still doesn't work.  It yields: $VAR1 = {
          'character_set_client' => 'cp850',
          'Database Collation' => 'latin1_swedish_ci',
          'collation_connection' => 'cp850_general_ci',
          'sql_mode' => '',
          'Create Function' => undef,
          'Function' => 'my_func'
        };

Comment: Verify that you're using same mysql user in script and command line with `select user();`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that user@localhost is not the same as user@remote_host (MySQL bites me on this every time :-(

What's bizarre is that user@remote_host HAS the required privilege, while user@localhost does not (I'm in a shared hosting environment and don't have access to privileges on database mysql)